# How to count only missing/blank values in char data type column

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is:

```
date       value       name
may02       22          s1
may03                   s1
may04       34          s2
may05       35          s2
may06                   s3
may07                   s3
may08       22          s3
```

Value is in char data type. My query is

```
select count(*) as missing_value from my_table  where value= “ “ group by name;
```

The above query is not working properly
I need to calculate only MISSING /BLANK count in Value column grouped by Name

O/P should be

```
name       missing_value
s1           1
s2           0
s3           2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN `value` IS NULL OR TRIM(`value`) = '' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
  AS missing_value 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY name;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bf26/1/0)**</kbd>

or (this will skip groups that don't have any empty/blank data though):

```
SELECT name,
  COUNT(*) as missing_value 
FROM my_table 
WHERE `value` IS NULL OR TRIM(`value`) = ''
GROUP BY name;
```